# List Plot in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I want to plot a list in QML

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtCharts 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    var list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    var list2 = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
    ChartView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        legend.visible: false
        
        LineSeries {
           XYPoint { x:  list1 ; y: list2  }     **//This is not working!!!!**
        }
    }
}
```

I want to plot list of data into QML graphs
List1 and List2 having 2 list of data, I want to plot all the data into a line series graph

Comment: A minor point, but, `list1` and `list2` should be declared using QML property syntax.

Comment: I will change and check once. THanks @StephenQuan

Comment: I have changed     var list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    var list2 = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17] into     property var list1 : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    property var list2 : [11,12,13,14,15,16,17]..Still not worked!

Comment: Check this example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtcharts-lineseries.html#details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill your `LineSeries` with a JavaScript function. Small example:

```
ChartView {
    id: chart
    anchors.fill: parent
    
    property var list1: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    property var list2: [11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
    
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; ++i) {
            line.append(list1[i], list2[i]);
        }
    }
    
    LineSeries {
        id: line
        
        axisX: ValueAxis {
            min: 0
            max: 7
        }
        
        axisY: ValueAxis {
            min: 0
            max: 17
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jürgen Lutz , The solution is working. One more query: Can we do this without for loop? Is there any possibility ?

Comment: @JeyanthInba did you mean to upvote the accepted answer?

Comment: @StephenQuan YES

Comment: @JeyanthInba Okay, just checking. Since, I thought the negative vote looked wrong. But, if you didn't do it, someone else might have.

Comment: @JeyanthInba I think (not 100% sure) you can use Instantiator to use your model without a loop. Use the len of liste as model and pick into each liste with index. Imho the loop is easier

Comment: @AntoineLaps Can you give me an example code to understand better. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JeyanthInba sorry, I try, but the LineSeries seam to not exist while there are nothing in it, so the Repeater is not load and there is no model to feed. that's weird, I learn something, thanks